# Z + Up arrow key doesn't work (Undertale)

Tags: keyboard, undertale

I am trying to solve the piano puzzle in Undertale. Unfortunately, I can't get the <kbd>up</kbd> or <kbd>left</kbd> arrow keys to produce a note. (NOTE: I am holding them then pressing <kbd>z</kbd>) Does anyone know whats going on? I am on a Windows 8.1 Desktop.

Answer (score 5):

This, most likely, is a result of your keyboard, not the game. Some keyboards have ghosting issues, especially low end ones. Try to test if  <kbd>Z</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd> works anywhere else, such as [this](http://www.keyboardtester.com/tester.html) website.

Answer (score 2):

This might be the issue because of keyboard ghosting. To fix this, try to reinstall the drivers of the keyboard. Another reason is might be your keyboard is defective or some of the keys are not working properly.

To check it, Visit [keyboardtester.io](https://keyboardtester.io) and check all the keys are working properly or not.